# Ipython Notebook: how to run multiple cells?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

My notebook gets a bit of long, I divide it into several parts.
Sometimes, I just want to run a certain part of it, i.e `consecutive cells`

For example, [image]

I want to run `Cell IN [52] to[54]`, not run `IN [51],[59]`. How can I do it?

I only know there is option for `run above`, `run below`, I didn't see anything like `run selected cells`.

---

UPDATE: Now Jupyter Notebook has this feature built-it, simply CTRL + click

[image]

Comment: You may want to have a look at the extension `Runtools`. You can find it in a nbextension collection at github: https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions

Comment: @cel that's very interesting, I've watch a video course at Udemy and a course at Harvard CS109, and never heard this before. This is very useful.

Comment: jupyter should absolutely add this feature, if not already

Comment: @Shockley, yes, and I'm wondering how can I add this feature if I want? I only know about Ruby on Rails. Addtionally, I also want a bookmark feature so I can navigate my code easily, without scrolling too much.

Comment: @cqcn1991 using CTRL + click does not work for me, but CTRL + SHIFT + click does

Comment: For Mac: Shift + Cmd and then run Shift + Enter

Answer (score 17, accepted):

UPDATE as per Jan 2018:
You can select and run multiple cells in command mode using the below shortcuts:

1.shift+K (select the cells in an upward direction) and then Ctrl+Enter

2.shift+J (select the cells in a downward direction) and then Ctrl+Enter

Comment: Could you also post a reference to this update, so users can follow up on that?  Thx.

Comment: Reference :  https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Notebook%20Basics.html#Keyboard-Navigation

Answer (score 4):

I found a useful extension that performs a similar function: init_cell.
First, you will need to install jupyter nbextensions configurator as described [here](https://github.com/Jupyter-contrib/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator).

Then search for **"Initialization cells"** from inside the search bar of the *Jupyter nbextension manager*.

A check box at the top of every cell will appear. You can select which cells to be marked as initialization cells.

To run all the initialization cells at once, click the button with calculator symbol on the tool bar:
[image: Initialization cells extension]

Along with cqcn1991's solution, you can gain a reasonable control over your notebook.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not the answer your are looking for (because its not the answer I was looking for) but for your specific case of running cells 52-54, because they are sequential and continuous, you can simply click the play button (run cell and select below) 3 times

[image]

and it will queue those cells for running.  This will work for a handful of sequential cells, but for out of sequence or really long blocks of cells, probably not the best ideal

Comment: Now the jupyter notebook support select and run multple cells.

Comment: Sweet, I must have an out of date version

Comment: @cqcn1991 I know this reply is very late, but where is this feature? I can't find it in Jupyter notebook

Comment: @OsamaSalah see my update. You can then `copy/delete/run` as using a single cell.

Comment: @cqcn1991 Thanks. But it doesn't work with me. Ctrl has no effect. However, I can use the Shift key to select multiple cells, but they have to be consecutive. Which browser do you use? I have Firefox on Linux Mint.

Comment: @OsamaSalah I'm on Firefox Win 7. Maybe you can ask for help in Jupyter Notebook's github issue.