# Jupyter notebook run all code between two cells

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way on Jupyter notebook to run the code between two specific cells? For instance, suppose that I have 100 cells and I want to run only cells from 35 to 60. I don't want to run everything again from 1 to 60 because, for instance, the cells from 1 to 34 might require a long time to execute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ipython Notebook: how to run multiple cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864681/ipython-notebook-how-to-run-multiple-cells)

Comment: By the way, your question's title is in contradiction with your question. On one hand you say, "run all code" and on the other hand you say "run only lines from 35 to 60". Also, is each line of your code in a different cell? Which means, do you have 100 cells with one line of code in each cell OR a single cell with 100 lines of code? lines and cells are two different things. You have to differentiate

Comment: @Bazingaa I am extremely sorry, I made a mistake, I meant cells, not lines. My sincere apologies. I have modified the question. It won't happen again

Comment: Try the answer in the link I gave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use shift+K  to select the cells (upward direction)/ shift+J (downward direction) and then Ctrl+Enter to execute